# 'addFirst' method in Linked List in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have a list I created:

```
struct list_t {
   int value;
   struct list_t* next;
};
```

My 'addFirst':

```
void addFirst(struct list_t* head,int value) {

    struct list_t* toAdd = (struct list_t*) malloc (sizeof (struct list_t));
    toAdd->value = value;

    toAdd->next = head;
    head = toAdd;
}
```

The thing is that when I add the new 'node' to the list, it works in the function (using
DDD debugger to see), but when I exit the function my list remains the same.

I know this can be done by making my method return a `struct list_t*` instead of `void`, and its also possible by passing in a pointer to the pointer of head as an argument (`struct list_t** PtoHead`) but my question is if its possible to do this using my method (i.e. returning `void` and having a pointer to the `head` as a parameter).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, but it'll be ugly.

If you link the new element in as element number 2, and move the data accordingly, you can replace the old head with the new while also adding a new element after it:

```
void addFirst(struct list_t* head, int value)
{
    struct list_t* toAdd = malloc(sizeof *toAdd);

    toAdd->value = head->value;
    head->value = value;
    toAdd->next = head->next;
    head->next = toAdd;
}
```

This assumes `head` isn't NULL, for that case I think it's impossible to solve using this prototype.

I would strongly recommend against doing that, it's very un-intuitive.

Comment: christ that's bad but I guess I have to do it seeing how i cant change the metod. Thank a bunch !

Comment: Nonetheless, a neat hack. +1.

Comment: @OnicaRadu Yeah this is very bad because if you saved anywhere else pointers to some structs, they are not pointing to the good value anymore after that. You should rather use the `struct list_t **head` method :)
 PS : Careful when naming your structs, list_t is more a typedef name than a struct name...